# Manually closing folder if autoCloseFolder set to false with ImapMailReceiver

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-mail

read spring-integration-mail I try to load the email's content including the attachments. As a result, I obviously set autoCloseFolder=false. Now, docs mention that the ClosableResource should be used to close it whenever it's required. I wonder though, how can I achieve such behaviour with integrationFlowContext? Is there any way to close determine the end of session and close the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no session lifecycle management in Java Mail API. Therefore no way you can catch its closed state someway.

The close folder hook is for those use-cases where you'd like to re-fetch a fresh metadata on the next receive cycle. But in most cases there is no need to close it at all. Starting with Spring Integration `6.0`, the folder is closed automatically, when no new messages from the mail box to process:

```
        finally {
            if (this.autoCloseFolder || ObjectUtils.isEmpty(messagesToReturn)) {
                closeFolder();
            }
        }
```